# Ansible - variable for a specific inventory

Tags: ansible

I have a multi environment & multi inventories setup within ansible (2.7.9).
With one of the inventories, I am wanting to set a global variable to be inherited by all the hosts within the inventory. For this purpose I added the variable into that specific inventory (`inventory/production/prodinv`):

```
[all:vars]
myvar="True"
```

And it works fine if I ran ansible against that specific inventory (`inventory/production/prodinv`). However, if I run ansible against the inventory directory (eg `inventory/production`) , I noticed that the variable is inherited on all the hosts across all the inventories - which isn't ideal because I only want the hosts within `firstenv` inventory to have the var defined.

Currently group_vars and host_vars are a symlink (for all the inventories) against a "shared" root group_vars and host_vars.

To add more clarity to my question, below is the structure of my ansible:

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── playbooks/
├── roles/
├── inventory/
│   │
│   ├── group_vars/
|   |
|   ├── host_vars/
|   |
│   ├── tnd/
│   │   ├── group_vars/ -> ../group_vars
│   |   ├── host vars/  -> ../host_vars
│   │   └── devinv      
│   │
│   ├── production/
│   │   ├── group_vars/ -> ../group_vars
│   |   ├── host vars/  -> ../host_vars
│   │   └── prodinv   
│
└── . .
```

I'm not sure how / where to define this var that should apply to all hosts/groups within a particular inventory, without running into the same issue. Ideas?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is two-fold.

1. Ansible applies the `group_vars` of a directory to all files and subdirectories within the specified inventory directory. So, `inventory/production/group_vars` will get applied to everything within `inventory/production`. This just gets masked when you explicitly limit your inventory further while running, like you did (`-i inventory/production/prodinv`).

   1. This means that you need to put the `group_vars` only being applied to `prodinv` in their own directory and not in the `inventory/production` directory. For example, `inventory/production/prodinv/group_vars`.
2. Your symlinks are set up in a way that if you run against `inventory`, you're going to have the same `group_vars` applied to all your inventories. You're not hitting this in your example, but you'll likely hit it in the future.